# React Context: Cannot access 'AuthContext' before initialization

Tags: javascript, reactjs, consumer

## The issue

I am trying to use Context to pass GitHub API authorised user data from the login page the the home page so that the user information can be displayed (avatar image, name etc.)

However whenever I try to access the context from my class component `Home` in `Home.js` I am told `Cannot access 'AuthContext' before initialization`.

## My Code

#### Login.js

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useContext } from "react";
import { Redirect } from "react-router-dom";
import Styled from "styled-components";
import { AuthContext } from "../App";

export default function Login() {
  const { state, dispatch } = useContext(AuthContext);
  const [data, setData] = useState({ errorMessage: "", isLoading: false });

  const { client_id, redirect_uri } = state;

  useEffect(() => {
    const url = window.location.href;
    const hasCode = url.includes("?code=");

    if (hasCode) {
      const newUrl = url.split("?code=");
      window.history.pushState({}, null, newUrl[0]);
      setData({ ...data, isLoading: true });

      const requestData = {
        code: newUrl[1]
      };
      const proxy_url = state.proxy_url;
      fetch(proxy_url, {
        method: "POST",
        body: JSON.stringify(requestData)
      })
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => {
          dispatch({
            type: "LOGIN",
            payload: { user: data, isLoggedIn: true }
          });
        })
        .catch(error => {
          setData({
            isLoading: false,
            errorMessage: "Sorry! Login failed: " + error
          });
        });
    }
  }, [state, dispatch, data]);

  if (state.isLoggedIn) {
    return <Redirect to="/" />;
  }

  return (
    <Wrapper>
      <section className="container">
        <div className="card">
          <span className="errorMessage">{data.errorMessage}</span>
          <div className="login-container">
            {data.isLoading ? (
              <div className="loader-container">
                <div className="loader"></div>
              </div>
            ) : (
              <>
                {
                }
                <a
                  className="login-link"
                  href={`https://github.com/login/oauth/authorize?scope=user&client_id=${client_id}&redirect_uri=${redirect_uri}`}
                  onClick={() => {
                    setData({ ...data, errorMessage: "" });
                  }}
                >
                  <span className="btn">Login with GitHub</span>
                </a>
              </>
            )}
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>
    </Wrapper>
  );
}

const Wrapper = Styled.section`
  .container {
      background-color: #333;
  }
`;
```

#### Home.js

```
import React from "react";
import { Redirect } from "react-router-dom";
import Styled from "styled-components";
import { AuthContext } from "../App";

class Home extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super()
    this.state = {
      'items': []
    }
  }
  render() {
    const { state, dispatch } = this.context
    if (!state.isLoggedIn) {
      return <Redirect to="/login" />;
    }
    const { avatar_url, name, public_repos, followers, following } = state.user
    const handleLogout = () => {
      dispatch({
        type: "LOGOUT"
      });
    } 
    return (
      <Wrapper>
        <div className="container">
          <div>
            <div className="profileBox">
              <button className="btn" onClick={()=> handleLogout()}>Logout</button>
              <img  className="avatarImage" src={avatar_url} alt="Avatar"/>
              <span>{name}</span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </Wrapper>
    )
  }
}

const Wrapper = Styled.section`
.content {
  background-color: lightgray;
}
`;
Home.contextType = AuthContext
export default Home
```

#### app.js

```
import React, { createContext, useReducer } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
import Home from "./components/Home";
import Login from "./components/Login";
import { initialState, reducer } from "./store/reducer";
import Styled from "styled-components";

export const AuthContext = createContext();

function App() {
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, initialState);

  return (
      <AuthContext.Provider
        value={{
          state,
          dispatch
        }}
      >
      <Router>
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/login" component={Login}/>
          <Route path="/" component={Home}/>
        </Switch>
      </Router>
      </AuthContext.Provider>
  );
}
export default App;
```

## What I have tried

I have attempted to move the `Home.contextType = AuthContext` into the `render()` however becuase the render is called twice (I think it is related to [this](https://mariosfakiolas.com/blog/my-react-components-render-twice-and-drive-me-crazy/)) on the first run it is an empty object, state and dispatch are not there. This leads to errors relating to `isLoggedIn` and other context related items being `"undefined"` so I did not think this would be the appropriate solution.
I have also tried using `statis contextType = AuthContext` both before the `constructor` declaration and after but neither of these worked for me.

I have also attempted to use `AuthContext.Consumer` but with no avail as when this we put in place within the `render()` I was then not able to access any other the data. But then I am happy to admit React is new to me and therefore I may have misunderstood how `Consumer` works.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: In your app.js, you are importing Home component that uses context that is exported later in your app.js file.

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out, that takes care of the why. But perhaps you could help me further? How do I avoid this and still maintain the functionality of using routes? As far as I know I still need to import Home into app so I can use it for the routing?

Comment: Just create and export context in a separate file and import it wherever you want. All components (files) may need (import) context, but context doesn't rely on any other file or component.